# a4j:push not using websockets and falling back to long-polling

Tags: ajax, jboss, websocket, richfaces, long-polling

I am using Richfaces 4.2.2 for my project and from [this link](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/StartingWithRichFacesPushOnVariousServletContainers), figured out that atmosphere 0.8.4 needs to be used for compatibility. I am able to get push working but it is using long-polling instead of websockets. Webserver is Jboss 8.2 (undertow).

Following configurations were done to achieve this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.push.initializeOnStartup</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
 <context-param>  
    <param-name>org.atmosphere.useBlocking</param-name>  
    <param-value>true</param-value>  
 </context-param>
```

On server side, push notifications are send to client using

```
TopicKey topicKey = new TopicKey(key);
TopicsContext topicsContext = TopicsContext.lookup();
topicsContext.publish(topicKey, message);
```

On client side, notifications are received as. I have added script block to use transport for push as websocket, but it seems to be failing.

```
<script>
   RichFaces.Push.transport = "websocket";  
   RichFaces.Push.fallbackTransport = "long-polling";  
</script>  

<a4j:region>
    <a4j:push address="update">
        <a4j:ajax event="dataavailable" render="someelements"/>
    </a4j:push>
</a4j:region>
```

Can anyone guide me along with the missing configurations? OR it is the limitation with the current version of richfaces/atmosphere that long-polling is the only supported transport mechanism?

Error as seen on javascript console:

[image]

Comment: The variable name is `RichFaces` but assuming that part was not copied if Atmosphere switched back to long-polling it means that it didn't find support for WebSockets, you should be seeing a message in the console.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I am getting error message in console. It states that "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://localhost:8080/prj/__richfaces_push?__richfacesPushAsync=1&pushSessionId=ea0b3624-d7d1-4419-a856-4a8fefdab836.".

But, I have latest firefox which supports websockets and webserver is JBoss 8,2 which also supports websockets. 

Please let me know, if you can guide me to the possible cause for this error.

Comment: @Makhiel Please let me know, if there are suggestions. I am still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at push.js of version 4.2.2.Final,

```
richfaces.Push.transport = "long-polling";// "websocket";
richfaces.Push.fallbackTransport = undefined;//"long-polling";
```

It should be `richfaces` not `RichFaces`. Mind the case sensitivity.

I am not sure why websocket is purposely commented out. Same code goes for version 4.3.7.Final, but for version 4.5.7.Final, websocket is not commented out anymore. So I suggest you to upgrade to version 4.5.7.